# Is this proof using the pumping lemma correct?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar, regular-language, regular-expressions

I have this proof and it goes like this:

---

We have a language $L = \{\text{w element of } \{0,1\}^* \mid w = (00)^n1^m \text{ for } n > m \}$.

Then, the following proof is given:

There is a $p$ (pumping length) for $L$. Then we have a word $w = (00)^{p+1}1^p$ and $w$ element of $L$ and $|w| \le p$. $w$ can be written as $xyz$ with $y$ not empty and $|xy| \le p$.
This implies that $y=(00)^n$ for $0 < n \le p$.

Now for all $i \ge 1$ it means $xy^iz = (00)^{p+n(i-1)+1}1^p$ is an element of $L$.
Hence $L$ is regular.

---

I can clearly see that this proof is wrong (at least that's what I think). I can see that three things are wrong:

1. The pumping lemma cannot be used to proof the regularity of a language!
2. One thing bothers me: $y=(00)^n$ could never hold for $0 < n \le p$ because $n$ can be $p$ and therefore $y=(00)^p$ which means that the length of $y$ is $2p$! Condition no. 2 of the pumping lemma won't hold because $|y| = 2p$ and the 2nd condition of the pumping lemma is $|xy| \le p$.
3. Another thing is that you should also consider $i = 0$. Oh, and if $i = 0$ and $n \ge 1$ we would get that $n \le m$ and not $n > m$!

My question is actually if my assumptions are correct because it didn't take me much time to figure this out. There is a chance that I missed something. Can someone clarify?

I'm not asking for a proof, so please don't give one. I just want to know if my assumptions are correct and if not what you would think is wrong?

Comment: To prettify, use \$latex\$. But before, what is `(00)` ?

Comment: You can use $\LaTeX$ to prettify your answer. [This meta post describes how to get started.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) I've also put through an edit to clean up your post for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clean up. @user1938185 (00) is just part of the language L.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comment before I get to your (1)-(3): $p$ and $P$ are not the same symbol, so either the pumping length is $p$, or it’s $P$, but you shouldn’t keep jumping back and forth between the two. I’ll use $p$.

1. This is correct: the pumping lemma is strictly a tool for showing that a language is **not** regular.
2. This objection is not really well-taken. It’s true that $n$ cannot be $p$, for the reason that you give, but that does not invalidate the statement that $y=(00)^n$ for some $n$ satisfying $0<n\le p$, which is what is actually intended there; after all, the fact that $2\ne 3$ does not invalidate the statement that $2=n$ for some $n$ satisfying $0<n\le 3$. However, we **cannot** actually conclude that $y=(00)^n$ for some $n$, because there’s no reason to think that the length of $y$ has to be even. What we **can** legitimately conclude is that $y=0^n$ for some $n$ such that $0<n\le p$.
3. Yes, one should always remember that $xy^iz$ is supposed to belong to $L$ for **all** non-negative integers $i$, including $i=0$; sometimes this is crucial to using the pumping lemma to prove that a language is not regular.

In fact if you correct the errors in this argument, you’ll have a proof that this $L$ is **not** regular.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also edited the post to improve readability, it should be better to read now. I guess to prove the non-regularity I have to show that there are more 0's then 1's. I understand now, thank you

Comment: @n00b1990: It’ll be a little more complicated than that. If $n$ is odd, then $xy^2z$ will have an odd number of $0$’s and therefore won’t be in $L$. If $n$ is even, see what happens when $i=0$. (And you’re welcome.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the proof is bogus, as Brian M. Scott's answer expertly explains.

It is easier to prove that the *reverse* of your language isn't regular, or (by minor adjusting the proof of the lemma to place the pumped string near the end, not the start) that it isn't regular.